# Template for specific content type

Tags: theming, 8

I've read documentation about name suggestions but I don't get it. 
My goal is to create a specific template used only with a specific content type (Drupal 8).

I've copied `page.html.twig` to edit the code inside a new file, named `page--recette.html.twig` (recette is the name of my content type) but this doesn't work.

`html--node--recette.html.twig` doesn't work neither.

Link : http://ofhjfqaj.preview.infomaniak.website/cms/recette-sans-gluten/tarte-tatin-comme-la-vraie

Answer (score 4):

You can provide node level content type templates with the pattern `node--node_type.html.twig`.

So, for an `article` it would be `node--article.html.twig`.

In your case, it would be `node--recette.html.twig`. You can also provide view mode level twigs the same way, with `node--node_type--view_mode.html.twig` files.

Lets say you wanted to customize the teaser display markup:

`node--recette--teaser.html.twig`

If you enable twig debugging, you can see in your HTML source (comments) which template is being used, and what other template pattern names are available to you:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates

Going any further than that, you would need to implement [hook_theme_suggestions_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x) to get more custom template names based on some sort of logic.

Comment: Do I need to rewrite all the page in this file ? 
https://pastebin.com/XaXKn4sr  here is the content of my node--recette.html.twig and it doesn't print anything ;(
Sorry, i'm really novice with twig.

Comment: No, the node level template only handles the content of a node. `page` level template controls output of of regions/markup in the theme.

Comment: Node template variables can be output with `{{ content.field_name }}` - content is the render array. `page.` would do nothing in the context of a node twig template.

Comment: Note: `{{ content.field_name }}` refers to fields on the node type.

Comment: I really don't get the logic behing it :( 
I'm using Views to create blocks for each field. In /structure/block, I place blocks (created with Views) in the regions I want.
How do I print the regions with my node--recette.html.twig ?

Comment: You can't do that out of the box. You'd either have to use block reference fields on the node, or use a preprocess function to load the blocks, render them, and inject them into the variables array for the node twig template. Region printing is not done at the node level.

Comment: Hi, I'm kinda stuck at the same issue my twig template is not rendering for my custom content my module name is cspace and path is cspace/templates/node--cspace.html.twig and the twig file only contains a heading at the moment, can you please point out what maybe the issue in my case?